# Spring MVC configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using eclipse and Jboss for my coding of a simple Spring MVC application. 
I have created an enterprise application and I set the context-root as myAppWeb in application.xml.

My web.xml details:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My springspringapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

<bean name="/a.htm" class="com.init.servlet.test.HelloController" />

</beans>
```

Now when I am entering the URL as

```
"http://localhost:8080/myAppWeb/a.htm"
```

I am getting and 404 error and the log message as:

```
" servlet.PageNotFound OO                 noHandlerFound() OO No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myAppWeb/a.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'".
```

I changed the config in my springspringapp-servlet.xml as

```
<bean name="/myAppWeb/a.htm" class="com.init.servlet.test.HelloController" />
```

Still it is not working.

Could anyone help me out regarding this?

thanks!

Comment: What do you think the `name` attribute of `<bean>` does and why?

Comment: You'll need to post the code of HelloController

Answer (score 0):

For my projects, the '*-servlet.xml' file is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

</beans>
```

The 'web.xml' file has a context listener to read the configuration when spring application is booting:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringAppServlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Then, the file pointed by the context listener ('/WEB-INF/SpringAppServlet.xm')contains your configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

<bean name="/hello.htm" class="com.init.servlet.test.HelloController" />

</beans>
```

Comment: If not explicitly specified in DispatcherServlet, the context implementation will build a default location from the namespace of the dispatcher servlet i.e., in this scenario /WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml. Why do you think you need a listener to solve this?

Comment: As per my understanding regarding the error is: while looking for the Controller class it is taking the context root also for search key.\nSecondly if I use the ContextLoaderlistener then how can I do the URL-Mapping?

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify Context loader listener in your web.xml by passing bean configuration file as context param as below

```
<context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringAppServlet.xml</param-value> </context-param>

<listener> <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> </listener>
```

Comment: What do you think this will change.